# Status Bar in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox4

Firefox 4 has introduced a new "floating status bar" which appears only when DOM resources are being loaded or when the user hovers over links.

I have developed a Firefox sidebar extension which only displays an IFRAME within it. This IFRAME source contains a HTML document that encapsulates the main logic for the extension (in JavaScript). This document contains some links here and there.

The problem is that when a user hovers over a link, the new floating status bar appears and covers portions of the GUI in an awkward position. Is there a way for me to disable this status bar? Remember that I'm running within a FF extension.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.
I think that is an elegant but stupid solution by Mozilla, because this status bar hide site's contents such as bottom bars.
Why constrain the client to solve it with expensive plugins?
Web developers have not a real solution I think, because the javascript functions that provides to "see" the statusbar are blocked by mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the best solution to your problem, but you should look at [Link Location Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/link-location-bar/) which gets rid of those things. Maybe you could use the code there as inspiration for writing code that makes the statusbar always show up on the right.